# Ran Bundle Update in Rails 3 & now getting an error in application.rb for ActionMailer config setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I ran bundle update in order to get an update on a few gems that I was having issues with and I'm now getting an error when launching the console. The error is listed below. I'm still a newb to rails (playing around with it in my offtime) so this is quite possibly something trivial.

**Error:**

```
/Users/chance/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:77:in `method_missing': undefined method `action_mailer' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x000001020fc280> (NoMethodError)
from /Users/chance/Sites/AppName/config/application.rb:35:in `<class:Application>'
from /Users/chance/Sites/AppName/config/application.rb:10:in `<module:AppName>'
from /Users/chance/Sites/AppName/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/chance/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:21:in `require'
from /Users/chance/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

**application.rb**
*[edited out host & password]*

```
 require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# If you have a Gemfile, require the gems listed there, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env) if defined?(Bundler)

module AppName
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)

    # Only load the plugins named here, in the order given (default is alphabetical).
    # :all can be used as a placeholder for all plugins not explicitly named.
    # config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]

    # Activate observers that should always be running.
    # config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector, :forum_observer

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    #config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # JavaScript files you want as :defaults (application.js is always included).
    config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(jquery rails)
    config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
      :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
      :port                 => 587,
      :domain               => "host.net",
      :user_name            => "test@host.net",
      :password             => "******",
      :authentication       => "plain"
     # :enable_starttls_auto => true
     }
   config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }


    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"
    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the below lines in your code

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
      :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
      :port                 => 587,
      :domain               => "host.net",
      :user_name            => "test@host.net",
      :password             => "******",
      :authentication       => "plain"
     # :enable_starttls_auto => true
   }
```

You have misplace  the code `config.action_mailer.smtp_settings`
if rails 3 `config.action_mailer.server_settings`

Answer (score 4):

It is inadvisable to run `bundle update` to update all the gems in one go. You should try and run `bundle update <gemname>` to update the gems one by one. It the latter case you at least know that things broke due to this update.

For now, revert to the older version (I hope that you are using version control) on your `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` and run bundle install and start over again as described above.